# Libgdx get Texture from Image or Drawable

Tags: java, image, libgdx, textures

I would like to get the Texture data out of an image, so it may be rendered directly, but I see no straightforward way of making it, google searches show the other way around only.

I am able to get the Drawable, but the interface doesn't specify the exact texture data, so there's no way that I see to convert an Image actor into a Texture.

What I am trying to achieve is to have brushes, where the data of the brushes are stored in the image of an `ImageButton`. So upon clicking on an `ImageButton` The user would be able to draw on the screen based on the image stored in the buttons.

How might I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper, I found a solution on the [forums](https://web.archive.org/save/https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16525):

> Your best bet is probably to draw your textures to a FrameBuffer with
> a 1:1 scale, then you can use
>
> `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap`
>
> To copy a pixmap off the FrameBuffer and resize as you wish.
>
> Something like this:
>
> ```
>     fb.begin();
>
>    
>     sb.begin();
>     sb.draw(texture, 0, 0);
>     sb.end();
>
>     Pixmap pm = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0, 0, width, height);
>
>     fb.end();
> ```

It's not exactly a texture, but it is exactly what I would have needed: the pixel data extracted from a drawable.

After much thought I decided that it is easier to just store the texture data redundantly next to to the `Imagebutton`s, and query directly the stored data, instead of using the `ImageButton` as a kind of container, which it shouldn't be.